# Action of group on $\mathbb{R}^2$ homeomorphic to $M \backslash\partial M$

Tags: general-topology, group-actions

The problem is to find a group $G$ and action of it on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\mathbb{R}^2 / G \approx M \backslash \partial M$. ($M$ - Möbius strip)

I took $G = \mathbb{Z}$ and action of it defined by $r \cdot (x, y) = (x + r, (-1)^r y)$.
The problem is that i can't show that this action induces required homemorphism.
My idea was to consider some $A \subset R^2$ such that $A / \sim$, where $\sim$ is inherited equivalence relation induced by given action, is homeomorphic to $M \backslash \partial M$. For example, we can take $A = [-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}] \times \mathbb{R}$, but to show that $\mathbb{R}^2/ G  \approx A / \sim$ is where i got stuck. Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: How about https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266744/this-quotient-space-is-homeomorphic-to-the-m%c3%b6bius-strip